# Python Flask SQLalchemy count rows of certain user

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, jinja2

I have a table rooms where user save rooms in. Each room has a foreign key `"users_id"` so I know which room belongs to which user.

I need to count all rooms of each user and display the number for my admin dashboard.

I have a solution but it feels not correct.

I am making two queries for all rooms and all users:

```
users = db_session.query(User).order_by(desc('id'))

rooms = db_session.query(Zimmer)
```

In my jinja2 I am the making loops to check which rooms belongs to which user. I am creating a list and append the rooms there for each user and then I use the jinja2 count method on the list variable, I also have to make the append variable `display: none;`:

```
{% for user in users %} 
    {% set total_rooms = [] %}
    {% for room in rooms %}
    {% if room.users_id == user.id %}
        <span class="make-display-none">
        {{ total_rooms.append(room) }}
        </span>
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    <p> Anzahl Objekte: {{ total_rooms|count }} </p>    
{% endfor %}
```

It works but I feel like there must be a better solution!

Answer (score 2):

You should use a join, and then count. First join the users table with the rooms table using the key userId. Then once you have have [joined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)) the tables, do a count on all of the rows.

You can find joins in SQLAlchemy [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/selectable.html).